# How to set custom js file in Laravel admin template

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-5, laravel-admin

I am using Laravel 5.8 with laravel-admin Template for admin. Now in some situation i need custom js and css file only for admin specific controller. How to add these Js and css in laravel-admin.

Comment: In some post i got this 
Admin::js("your path")
But if i use this then What will be the path for custom js?

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
Admin::js('...your path here');
```

The path refers to the public directory. So, if you have a js file under `public` directory, use `'your_file_name.js'`. Or if you had your js file containing in a `public` subdirectory, use `Admin::js('sub_directory/your_file.js')`